# New to GitHub, how to run the commands on Windows?

Tags: git, git-bash

new to GitHub the website, so how to run the commands like:

```
$ sudo apt-get install npm
```

in Windows environment?

I installed Git Bash and run the command above but received a `command not found`message.

How to start? Thanks.

Comment: This is how you install npm on windows: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm#windows-install-or-upgrade

Comment: So all of those commands on GitHub are meant for Linux? I am not installing npm. It is just an example.

Comment: With apt-get you can install and manage software on your computer. It is called a Package management system. There are even more then just apt, but apt is used on Debian which is only one distribution of linux. Maybe wikipedia helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool

Comment: Huh? How to run all of those commands such as  '$ sudo apt-get install npm' '$ sudo npm install -g grunt-cli' in a Windows environment? Besides Git Bash what do I need?

Comment: As far as I know apt is not available on Windows. But maybe this can help you https://chocolatey.org/

Comment: If you install npm (anyways) the npm commands (commands starting with [sudo] npm) should work

Answer (score 0):

The specific command you ran only works on linux because:

- sudo is a linux command (or *nix command in general)
- apt-get is a linux command (specifically ubuntu/debian command)
- install is a argument to apt-get command
- npm is a package

So the line:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

means:
Hey package-manager(apt-get), install the package (npm) and do it as if I'm the superuser (sudo).

So the answer to your question is you cannot run *linux* commands from windows
But, you can run git commands to interact with github from Windows (using Git bash for example)

You have use the 'git' program to interact with github. (Git bash installs this program on Windows. If you were using linux you'd install git using "apt-get install git")

Here's a snippet from the git-for-windows webpage [ https://git-for-windows.github.io/ ]

> Git BASH Git for Windows provides a BASH emulation used to run Git
>   from the command line. *NIX users should feel right at home, as the
>   BASH emulation behaves just like the "git" command in LINUX and UNIX
>   environments.